# sql contains() with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflakes db and I want to write contain with multiple conditions like below:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CONTAINS(temp_CREATIVE_SIZE, '"480x320" OR "320x48"') THEN '320x480'
        WHEN CONTAINS(temp_CREATIVE_SIZE, '1024x768')  THEN '768x1024'
        WHEN CREATIVE_NAME ILIKE '%test%' THEN NULL
        WHEN CONTAINS(CREATIVE_NAME, '"interstitialvideo" OR "videointerstitial"') THEN '320x480'
        ELSE temp_CREATIVE_SIZE 
        END AS CREATIVE_SIZE
FROM my_schema
```

However the output still gives me 480x320 and 320x48. The contains() with single case works fine, it's the multiple cases that is not working. Is there another way of writing contains that I am not aware of?

Comment: `320x48` is not the mirror of `480x320`

Comment: also is your problem the CASE statement, if not just show the problem you seeing with CONTAINS, and if you have problems try past some demo input, as part of the SQL as other have done to show you how it's done.

Comment: is mirroring necessary? I'm just trying to put multiple conditions into contains(), if temp_creative_size contains any of 480x320 or 320x48 then I want to write 320x480 instead.

Comment: ok, this is some _interesting_ data wrangling.. it just fails some code smells so I am asking about some of them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONTAINS is not a regex, it's faster than ILIKE because it's just a substring present or not.

Thus reworking you demo problem

```
SELECT size,
    CASE 
        WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '"480x320" OR "320x48"') THEN '320x480'
        WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '1024x768')  THEN '768x1024'
        WHEN size ILIKE '%test%' THEN NULL
        WHEN CONTAINS(size, '"interstitialvideo" OR "videointerstitial"') THEN '320x480'
        ELSE 'else_'||size 
        END AS CREATIVE_SIZE
FROM (VALUES ('a480x320'),('480x320a'),('a320x480'),('320x480a'),('3testa'),('1024x768a') v(size));
```

gives:

```
SIZE    CREATIVE_SIZE
a480x320    else_a480x320
480x320a    else_480x320a
a320x480    else_a320x480
320x480a    else_320x480a
3testa      null
1024x768a   768x1024
```

showing you OR does not work.

What you want it to OR the CONTIANS or just have two WHERE CLAUSES

```
SELECT size,
    CASE 
        WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '480x320') THEN '320x480'
        WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '320x48') THEN '320x480'
        WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '1024x768')  THEN '768x1024'
        WHEN size ILIKE '%test%' THEN NULL
        WHEN CONTAINS(size, '"interstitialvideo" OR "videointerstitial"') THEN '320x480'
        ELSE 'else_'||size 
        END AS CREATIVE_SIZE
FROM (VALUES ('a480x320'),('480x320a'),('a320x480'),('320x480a'),('3testa'),('1024x768a') v(size));
```

gives:

```
SIZE    CREATIVE_SIZE
a480x320    320x480
480x320a    320x480
a320x480    320x480
320x480a    320x480
3testa  
1024x768a   768x1024
```

or:

```
WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '480x320') OR CONTAINS(SIZE, '320x48') THEN '320x480'
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I initially used multiple contains() but I wanted to clean up the code a little more and ran into this problem, now I know why it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that supports multiple patterns is `LIKE ANY`.

Instead of:

```sql
WHEN CONTAINS(SIZE, '"480x320" OR "320x48"') THEN '320x480'
// doesn't work
```

You can write:

```sql
WHEN SIZE LIKE ANY ('%480x320%', '%320x48%') THEN '320x480'
// works
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any.html